# Azure Devops: Model Register and package through Azure CLI in Devops pipeline Task

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-machine-learning-service

While Registering the model in Azure devops pipeline task through Inline script, its giving below issue:

Command:

```
az ml model register -g $(ml.resourceGroup) -w $(ml.workspace) -n model_test --model-path ./Configuration/outputs/ -t model.json
```

Error:

> Encountered authorization while uploading to blob storage. Please
> check the blob storage account attached to your workspace. Make sure
> current user is authorized to access the storage account and that the
> request is not blocked by firewall , virtual network and other
> security setting.
>
> status code: 403

can someone help e on above issue?

Answer (score 1):

I think I've seen this before. Probably you have an outdated version of the CLI. Pease run:

```
az upgrade
az extension update -n ml
```

Comment: Tried this command az upgrade --yes, its giving below error:                                  
WARNING: Downloading MSI to C:\Users\AzDevOps\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpy5p35ma7\azure-cli-2.30.0.msi
WARNING: Installing MSI
##[error]Exit code -1073741510 returned from process: file name 'C:\agent\externals\node10\bin\node.exe', arguments '"C:\a\_tasks\AzureCLI_46e4be58-730b-4389-8a2f-ea10b3e5e815\2.1.2\azureclitask.js"'.

Comment: Also, i have seen this in MS doc: az upgrade is supported on Windows, macOS and some Linux distros as long as installation is supported. It only supports upgrading to the latest version. If you are running the Azure CLI through Azure Cloud Shell, you are most likely already using the most recent Azure CLI install. If not due to cases like ad-hoc release of a minor bug fix version, you need to wait for the next build of Azure Cloud Shell as az upgrade is not supported in Azure Cloud Shell.                                         https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/update-azure-cli

Comment: Got it. I just read the part that you were running on Azure Devops. So probably this command is running under a Service Principal account. Assuming you already make an Azure Login step, the service account may not have access to the underlying BLOB storage account. Please grant Contributor to all the components used by Azure ML (the workspace, the blob storage account, the key vault) since this won't happen automatically.